# Posting data from view to controller in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

net mvc. i am not being able to send data from client side to controller. suppose i have one form. there is two sets of input controls. one set is for login and another set is for registration but both controls are in one form. **without using JavaScript to post form how can i post data from view to controller**. there would be two different function in controller named login & register.

there will be two buttons control name Login & register in same form. when user fill up login details and click on login button then login data will be post to controller and login action method will be called.

when user fill up registration details and click on register button then registration related data will be post to controller and register action menthod will be called.

please help me with sample code for view & controller. thanks

Comment: If they are both within one form, they must go to one controller action. It's either Javascript, or you split this up into two forms

Comment: If you explain why you do not want to use two forms, helping you will become easier. It seems you know that you should be using two forms

Comment: Please show your `View` and `Controller` code so we can help you.

Comment: ok i have no prob for two form. please help me with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following (one form, one controller action):

**VIEW:**

```
[...]
<input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Login" />
<input type="submit" id="register" name="register" value="Register" />
```

**CONTROLLER ACTION:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginRegister(MyModel myModel, string login, string register)
{
    if (login == null)
    {
        // Button "Register" clicked
        [...]
    }

    if (register == null)
    {
        // Button "Login" clicked
        [...]
    }

    [...]

}
```

Comment: You should never have one action do multiple, semantically different, things. What if you want to also register a Facebook account to login? Do you do `LoginRegiserFacebook` and add yet _another_ check? What if you want to add something else? There should be one `Login` action and one `Register` action.

Comment: All your "What ifs" were not included in the original question. I simply answered to a specific question, not given ASP.NET MVC development guidelines.

Comment: Regardless of the "what ifs", the original point stands. If we are guiding someone inexperienced with the framework, we might as well guides them toward best practices.